# Select part from grouped data where all the records in grouped data satisfy any incoming criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

part grouping table:

| part | attribute | code | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PN1 | A | 1 | 1 |
| PN1 | B | 2 | 1 |
| PN1 | C | 3 | 1 |
| PN2 | A | 1 | 2 |
| PN2 | B | 2 | 2 |

incoming criteria:

| attribute | Code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |

in the result, PN2 should be selected as all the records in group 2 satisfies the incoming criteria.

have the incoming criteria been (A,1),(B,2), (C,3)  both the parts should be selected.

Comment: What is your question here? Why repeat your last sentence? How does that help us understand your (omitted) question?

Comment: result should give the part column data as per incoming criteria.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what you're asking.

Comment: You can assume incoming criteria as 1 table and part grouping table as another. Result should include part column values, whose all the records (Attribute, code) are contained in the incoming criteria table.

Comment: I think what Thom A is saying is that you have not asked a question. You have described a task, but forgot to tell us what you want from us. As is, our answer could be "Great, good luck with it!" which is probably not the answer you are after. So, there is a task, and you have (hopefully) tried to solve it yourself. But you got stuck. What have you tried? Where did that fail? What is it that you cannot solve yourself? What is the question you want to ask us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all those parts for which does not exist a row in the grouping table that has no match in the criteria table.

One way is to outer join the criteria and then aggregate per part and see if you get as many matches as there are rows in the grouping table.

```
select pa.part
from part_attributes pa
left join criteria c on c.attribute = pa.attribute and c.code = pa.code
group by pa.part
having count(*) = count(c.code)
order by pa.part;
```